# Script to get file from SFTP and run it

Tags: ssh, scripting, authentication, sftp

We have 5 servers running our code: A, B , C, D and E.

From a local machine, we sftp the file to A. Then

```
ssh id@A
su - applicationname
sftp id@A
get <file>
bye
tar -xzf <file>
logout
logout
```

The same procedure we apply for others B to E.

Is there any way we can simplify this using script?

We have requested linux team to provide passwordless authentication. But we don't know how to do sftp inside a SSH session using a script.

Comment: Use scp instead.

Answer (score 5):

Best and easiest is to use `scp` instead of `sftp`.

If `scp` is really not an option, you can read `sftp` commands using a 'here document', but **it is very hard to script around errors**.

```
sftp username@server << %EOF%
ls
bye
%EOF%
```

`%EOF%` can be any word you want, as long as it starts and ends with a `%` and the last `%EOF%` must be at the start of a line.

For passwordless login, read up on 'ssh key authentication'.

Using `sftp` from within an `ssh` session sounds like overkill, sounds like doing double things. Why not initiate the copy from the local machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lftp` to do password authentication from a script. Password-less authentication can be very dangerous sometimes. Since I see that you are invoking this script for multiple servers, you will have to manually enter the passwords every time you use `sftp`.

Instead, you can use `lftp` to put your password inside the script and run it as a cron-job. Although you will be needing different files for each server. Nevertheless, all of them can be run through a cron-job to run `*.sh` inside a directory that contains each copy of the script.

Steps to follow for password authentication from a script:

1. firstly install lftp using `yum install lftp` or `sudo apt-get install lftp`, according to the linux flavor.
2. write a script as below:

   ```sh
   #!/bin/sh

   HOST='ec2#####.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com'

   USER='ubuntu'

   PASSWD='ubuntuuser'

   cd directory/where/you/want/to/put/or/get/a/file

   lftp << END_OF_SCRIPT
   open sftp://$HOST
   user $USER $PASSWD
   cd /home/anywhere_you_want_the_file_from/
   mput *.txt
   END_OF_SCRIPT
   ```

---

Note, please change the *hostname, username* and *password* according to your server. Also this script uses 'mput' to get multiple files at `/home/anywhere_you_want_the_file_from/` location at remote location to the local. If single file is needed 'put' can be used. Any commands of sftp can be used inside the `END_OF_SCRIPT`.

Comment: Welcome to U&L! Please take note of the formatting changes I made (they were rather significant). Quote blocks are not well-suited for code, and bold (if it should even be used at all) should not be used for inlined commands.